# Hide "Update" notification for Xcode on macOS Mojave, Xcode is not installed

Tags: applications, xcode, mac-appstore, mojave

I'm running 10.14.1 and Software Updater says everything is up to date.

But App Store insists in telling I have a "Pending Update" for Xcode, even though I don't have Xcode installed. (I just have the command line tools installed.)

How do I get App Store to stop telling me to update Xcode?